# redimensionar data frame

Tags: r

Como podría "redimensionarse" o recortarse dos dataframes por el valor de una de sus columnas? Mi objetivo es operar con ellos, osea realizar la diferencia de los valores para las fechas coincidentes.

No se si podria hacerse de una manera eficiente sin tener que crear variables que almacenen los dos dataframes y poder calcular el error.

Los Datos:
dos dataframes de 2 columnas(tiempo y valor) con diferentes longuitudes, una empieza mas tarde que otra y termina despues que la segunda.

```
df1
         time   value
    1  2001-02-01 107
    2  2001-04-01 122
    3  2001-06-01 123
    4  2001-08-01 101
    5  2001-10-01 130
    6  2001-12-01 116
    7  2002-02-01 108
    8  2002-04-01 154
    9  2002-06-01 146
    10 2002-08-01 111
    11 2002-10-01 110
    12 2002-12-01 133
```

df2

```
  time   value

3  2001-06-01 223
4  2001-08-01 131
5  2001-10-01 134
6  2001-12-01 16
7  2002-02-01 228
```

dfR   Resultado deseado:

```
3  2001-06-01 100
4  2001-08-01 30
5  2001-10-01 4
6  2001-12-01 -100
7  2002-02-01 120
```

Edito: # una posible solucion es hacer un merge por "time" y luego operar...

```
dfR<- merge(df1,df2, by = c("time"))
```

Alguna otra mejor solucion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, quieres que de una vez salga `dfR` como lo pusiste en el ejemplo. Lo mas facil aqui es usar `dplyr`. En este caso, podria ser:

```
dfR <- df1 %>% 
  right_join(df2, by="time") %>% 
  transmute(time=time, diferencia=value.y-value.x)
```

donde dfR da el resultado deseado:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
        time diferencia
      <date>      <int>
1 2001-06-01        100
2 2001-08-01         30
3 2001-10-01          4
4 2001-12-01       -100
5 2002-02-01        120
```

Mira que aqui hicimos un `right_join()`, hay otras formas de unir las tablas (dejando o eliminando filas) descritas en el [la hoja de referencia Domar Datos](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/data-wrangling-spanish.pdf). Alli tambien vez que puedes escojer dejar los resultados previos con `mutate` o ignorarlo con `transmute` como lo hicimos aqui arriba.